# How do I attach event handler to current event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling

I want to make a list of ingredients and make it possible to increase de number of ingredients by clicking on the 'plus' button.

What happens now is when I click the plus button of the second ingredient, the number of the first ingredient increases.

`HTML`

```
<div>
    <div class="ingr"><button>+</button><p><span>1</span> thea spoon(s) of sugar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ingr"><button>+</button><p><span>2</span> courgettes</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`JavaScript`

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let num = document.querySelector('span');

var count = 0;

const increase = function(event) {
  count++;
  num.innerHTML = count;
}

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = increase;
}
```

Comment: Because they are sharing the same count value. And you are changing innerHTML of the `num` which is a reference to only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code it would be fiddly to have to query each of the buttons sibling elements in order to increment them. In this solution you can loop over all the `.ingr` nodes and apply functionality to them and their children by calling `Ingredientize` on them. I have expanded the logic/html to handle decreasing the amount as well.

```js
function Ingredientize (el) {
  const Incrementor = el.querySelector('button.incrementor')
  const Decrementor = el.querySelector('button.decrementor')
  const QuantityElement = el.querySelector('span')
  
  const renderQuantity = value => QuantityElement.innerHTML = value
  
  let quantity = +QuantityElement.innerHTML || 0
  
  Incrementor.addEventListener('click', () => renderQuantity(++quantity) )
  Decrementor.addEventListener('click', () => renderQuantity(--quantity) )
}

const ingredients = document.querySelectorAll('.ingr')
ingredients.forEach(ingredientElement => Ingredientize(ingredientElement))
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="ingr">
      <button class="incrementor">+</button>
      <button class="decrementor">-</button>
      <p>
        <span>1</span> thea spoon(s) of sugar
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="ingr">
      <button class="incrementor">+</button>
      <button class="decrementor">-</button>
      <p>
        <span>2</span> courgettes
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `span` that is returned by `document.querySelector('span')` and assigned to variable `num` on line 2 is the first `span` in the document. The reference to `num` on line 8 within the `increase` function is a reference to that first `span`. If you would like to change the `span` that is a sibling of the clicked `button`, you can select that `span` by referencing the button within the `increase` function as the `event.target`:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

const increase = function(event) {
  var buttonParentDiv = event.target.parentNode;
  var buttonSiblingSpan = buttonParentDiv.querySelector("span");
  buttonSiblingSpan.innerHTML++
}

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = increase;
}
```